# 3D Vector structure from c++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, vector, struct, marshalling

I'm trying to port some functionality from my engine from c++ to C#.
I compile my engine as a dll with unmanaged c++ and only use extern "C" functions in the C# wrapper.

I have various functions that take and return `Vector3df`. This is defined as

```
typedef Vector3d<f32> Vector3df;
```

and `f32` is a actually a `float`. The class itself has nothing more than some members called x y and z and a lot of methods.

I can rewrite the whole class in C#, that's not a problem but is there anyway in which the 2 could be matched?

Let's take for example the following functions:

```
extern "C" void SetColor(Vector3df color)
extern "C" Vector3df GetColor()
```

I would like to have something like this in C#:

```
[DllImport("Engine.dll", EntryPoint = "SetColor", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern void SetColor(Vector3df color);
[DllImport("Engine.dll", EntryPoint = "GetColor", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern Vector3df GetColor();
```

Is there anyway in which I could make code similar to this work?

Note that I'm not by any means a C# guru.I'm lost when it comes to marshaling. I'm mostly doing this to make a map editor for my game without having to learn Qt or wxWidgets.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is define a C# structure that has an equivalent binary layout to the one expected by the c++ dll. Assuming only x,y,z with no packing, that's just...

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] //Required, as default layout is Auto
struct Vector3df {
    public float x, y, z;
}
```

That should work with the C and C# function signatures you've given. The difficulty arises if you wish to invoke any method on the Vector3df class, because you cannot p/invoke C++ class methods. You need to wrap each of the methods as a plain C function as you've done with the Set/GetColor.

It ends up being a lot of work if you're trying to import a big library, and might be simpler to use C++/CLI to create the wrapper. Another option might be to investigate using [cxxi](https://github.com/mono/cxxi), but I have no experience using this.

Comment: Could I write something like that but use a class and include some methods? I have no problem in writing the vector functions again in C#

Comment: You can use a class, and you can add methods, just make sure you don't add any fields that would give it a different binary representation to what the native class is expecting.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way might be to just create another C++/CLI wrapper DLL where you do the conversion between unmanaged and managed C++ classes.