# How to marshal a vector<double> from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, vector, marshalling

My current work-around is to, from C#, get the size of the vector using:

```
[DllImport("BridgeInterface.DLL", EntryPoint = "#46", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl]
private static extern int GetVectorSize();
```

where `BridgeInterface.dll` is a C++ bridge interface between my C++ and C# code. I then marshal each vector element using:

```
[DllImport("BridgeInterface.DLL", EntryPoint = "#47", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl]
private static extern double GetVectorElement(int index);
```

Is there a way to marshal the entire vector using a single call into C++?

Comment: possible duplicate of [3D Vector structure from c++ to C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313600/3d-vector-structure-from-c-to-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

std::vector<>, per the standard, must reside in continuous memory space. So all your `double`s are in one memory chunk so it can be marshalled as a single memory buffer (take the pointer to first element and do `size() * sizeof(double)` for the length of the buffer). After that it's reduced to the case of marshalling an array of `double`s and I found [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d516ec43-52fd-4c64-a414-dff3b1aa3168/how-to-marshalling-a-double-array-between-cc?forum=clr) post on explaining how (with and without copying to C# memory space).

Answer (score -1):

Using a DataStructure with fixed length will help you get rid of the Length Check.

[3D Vector structure from c++ to C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313600/3d-vector-structure-from-c-to-c-sharp?rq=1)

Comment: Referencing a P/Invoke website which is full of TODOs is not very helpful. Neither is referencing a search query which returns different results every day.

Comment: @ThomasW. Point noted, thus answer changed. Thank You.